# Rust lazy static custom struct instance

Tags: string, struct, rust, lazy-static

In Rust, I am trying to declare a static instance of a custom struct.

Because by default I am not able to assign other values than const ones, I am trying to use lazy_static.

Here is my custom struct:

```
pub struct MyStruct { 
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    field3: u32
}
```

Here is how I am trying to instantiate it:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref LATEST_STATE: MyStruct = {
        field1: "".to_string(),
        field2: "".to_string(),
        field3: 0
    };
}
```

This code does not compile with the following error:

```
error: expected type, found `""``
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref LATEST_STATE: MyStruct = MyStruct {
                                     // ^^^^^^^^
        field1: "".to_string(),
        field2: "".to_string(),
        field3: 0
    };
}
```

Lazy_static initialization is the same as normal Rust. `let mystruct: MyStruct = { field: "", ... };` won't compile. You need the typename before the `{}` otherwise its interpreted as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"".to_string()` try to instantiate with `String::from("")`.

Comment: Probably even better nowadays is String::default()